# How to make the autocomplete handler work in Discord.Net?

Tags: discord, discord.net

I'm sorry if it sound a bit newbie, but i'm stuck trying to get working the AutocompleteHandler.
Following the documentation, i tried to create a very basic autocomplete system :

```
public class ExampleAutocompleteHandler : AutocompleteHandler
{
    public override async Task<AutocompletionResult> GenerateSuggestionsAsync(IInteractionContext context, IAutocompleteInteraction autocompleteInteraction, IParameterInfo parameter, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        // Create a collection with suggestions for autocomplete
        IEnumerable<AutocompleteResult> results = new[]
        {
            new AutocompleteResult("Name1", "value111"),
            new AutocompleteResult("Name2", "value2")
        };

        // max - 25 suggestions at a time (API limit)
        return AutocompletionResult.FromSuccess(results.Take(25));
    }
}
```

In the module :

```
public class ItemModule : InteractionModuleBase
{
    // you need to add `Autocomplete` attribute before parameter to add autocompletion to it
    [SlashCommand("command_name", "command_description")]
    public async Task ExampleCommand([Summary("parameter_name"), Autocomplete(typeof(ExampleAutocompleteHandler))] string parameterWithAutocompletion)
        => await RespondAsync($"Your choice: {parameterWithAutocompletion}");

}
```

I tried to register the handler as a Singleton, but nothing worked. It doesnt display the list when i type the commands.

I appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the documentation is currently missing this.
Just like Slash Commands, you need to handle the Autocompletion event and forward it to your interaction service.

On your discord client, handle the event

```cs
_client.AutocompleteExecuted += async (SocketAutocompleteInteraction arg) => {
    var context = new Discord.Interactions.InteractionContext(_client, arg, arg.Channel);
    await _interactionService.ExecuteCommandAsync(context,services: _serviceProvider);
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement same function. The GenerateSuggestionsAsync function from ExampleAutocompleteHandler  is never called. _client.AutocompleteExecuted is called correctly ... But I'm not sure for the _serviceProvider variable, I declare null instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to integrate AutoCompleteHandler too. And I have the same issue ... The autocomplete proposition is empty :

[image]

I tried to add handle AutoCompleted event (like Dedmen Miller says), and Also the InteractionCreated too ... But, window still empty. The 2 handlers are called, but the ExecuteCommandAsync do nothing ...